# Storing additional values to photos stored on dropbox

Tags: android, dropbox

I'm making a photo calendar where you can take a photo for day you choose, so when I am storing photos on dropbox I also need to somehow store dates of these photos. What is the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just put the date in the filename? E.g. `2013-12-13.jpg`.

If you don't want to do that, I suppose you could use the [Datastore API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore) to keep track of a mapping of dates to filenames.